# Reading the import table of a running process

Tags: c++, windows, import, portable-executable

Is there a way to read the the import table of another process?
The function `ImageNtHeader` won't help me here, because it applies only to my process and not to the other process.
I know I can read the entire file and parse its PE header, but I'm afraid it will take a lot of time if the file is large.

Is there a way to do it using the process's memory directly and not reading from the file?
Any other easy and nice way to do it will be great as well :)

Comment: There is zero point in trying to access the memory of another process when the exact same info is available in a file.  95% odds that it is in the file system cache anyway so you are actually reading from memory.

Comment: Use Dll-injection to call ImageNtHeader remotely. That's the nicest way I can think of to read the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` without actually accessing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use psapi or toolhlp32 to find the memory addresses of the processes modules you are interested in. once you have that you can use `ReadProcessMemory` get the required info. else just pretend to be a debugger and attach to the target process so you have full access to it's memory, then you can use the windows PE macros.

Comment: ok, but if I open the other process as a debugger. Which functions can I use to read its PE header. I only found functions for the current process...

Comment: @Idov: you can use `ImageNtHeader` if you have full memory read permissions, just pass it the `HMODULE` of the exe or dll you wish to examine from the process you attached to. if you lack memory read permissions then you need to use `ReadProcessMemory`